# CloudPage Bugs - Content Builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, cloudpage

I've acquired a list of bugs that I'm seeing within the Content Builder version of CloudPages (not ideal, but necessary to use drop & drag blocks in my use case):

1. Button styling reverts on all buttons even though styles have been saved and published
2. Intermittent freezing out of UI: still trying to trace back the steps to replicate this one, but once UI freezes, all is lost.  Save often.
3. 2 column, 1 row layout text layout bleeds on mobile version (if using Align Right)
4. Smart Capture error messages appear to left of field (not technically a bug, but pretty annoying that orientation cannot be managed).

Is there a place to log these?  They are not in KNOWN ISSUES within Salesforce

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the type, there are these two options:

- **Bug:** Open a case in the Salesforce Help & Training portal with the information, that you like to report a bug and how this can be reproduced.
- **Idea/Feature request** (for example number 4 in your list): Unfortunately this is a bit trickier, as you can only post it on IdeaExchange and hope that your idea gets enough votes for Salesforce to look into it.

**Links:**

- [Help & Training portal - Contact Support](https://help.salesforce.com/mysuccesshub?id=solutionFinder)
- [IdeaExchange](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaSearch)